# 403 You don't have permission to access this folder after removing hashbang on AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs, .htaccess

i was trying to remove hashbang from URL of angularjs application, i found an solution by htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

it works fine on locathost XAMPP but when i upload it to my web server cPanel, it can't access any PHP file or folder directly, it shows error: 403
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /anotherFolder/index.php on this server.

I can access the file if i remove this htaccess

Please help
thanks

Comment: Set file permissions to 777 and try to connect again.

Comment: after 777 its not working :(

Comment: I can access the file if i remove this htaccess

Comment: Unfortunetly I wouldn't be able to help you with that ;/.

Comment: can u check out with condition in your .htaccess like this <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>      rewrite rules        </IfModule>

Comment: see my answer below, anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i ended up by replacing:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```

with:

```
RewriteEngine On 
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /#/$1 [L]
```